# Ansible custom tool ,retry and redeploy

Tags: deployment, ansible, continuous-deployment

I am trying to use Ansible as a deployment tool for a set of hosts and I'm not able to find the right way of doing it.

I want to run a custom tool that installs rpm in a host.

Now I can do

```
ansible dev -i hosts.txt -m shell -a "rpmdeployer --install package_v2.rpm"
```

But this doesn't give a retry file(failed hosts)
I made a playbook to get the retry file

I tried a simple playbook

```
---
- hosts: dev
  tasks: 
    - name: deployer
     command: rpmdeployer --install package_v2.rpm
```

I know this not in the spirit of ansible to execute custom commands and scripts. Is there a better way of doing this? Also is there a way to keep trying till all hosts succeeds?

Comment: Please show the log of the run. And add -vvv at final. In the ansible launch command. The explain more about, why the hosts failed? And. You want get the ouput of your command or retry and run the same command when failed the first time.

Comment: It can vary from system being unstable to rpm db being corrupt. I am not interested in why it failed(sys admins will take care of that) i want to retry so that once the other issues are resolved I don't have to manually retry failed hosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way of doing this?

You can [write a custom module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_modules.html). The custom module could even *be* the tool, so you get rid of installing that dependency. Modules can be written in any language but it is advisable to use Python because:

1. Python is a requirement of Ansible anyway
2. When using Python you can use the API provided by Ansible

If you'd have a custom module for your tool your task could look like this:

```
- name: deployer
  deployer: package_v2.rpm
```

> Also is there a way to keep trying till all hosts succeeds?

Ansible can automatically [retry](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#do-until-loops) tasks.

```
- name: deployer
  command: rpmdeployer --install package_v2.rpm
  register: result
  until: result | success
  retries: 42
  delay: 1
```

This works, given your tool returns correct exit codes (0 on success and >0 on failure). If not you can apply any custom condition, e.g. search the `stdout` for content etc.

I'm not aware of a tool to automatically retry when the playbook actually failed. But it shouldn't be too hard create a small wrapper script to check for the retry file and run the playbook with `--limit @foo.retry` until it is not re-created.

But I'm not sure that makes sense. If installing an rpm with your tool fails, I guess it is guaranteed it will also fail on any retries, unless there are unknown components in the play like downloading the rpm in the first place. So of course the download could fail then and a retry might succeed.